# Set maximum length for field in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I want to set max length from default.php.
Here is my XML format,

```
<fieldset name="sender_details">
    <field name="sendername"
     type="text"
     label="SENDERV_SENDER"
     description="SENDERV_SENDER_DESC"
     default=""
     required="true" />
 </fieldset>
```

Here is the coding for default.php.

```
foreach ($this->form->getFieldset('sender_details') as $field) :
  echo $field->label;
  echo $field->input;
 }
```

I had a variable $length=5.The text box should allow only 5 characters.The length is coming from the configuration. I need to do in default.php

kindly Help Me.

Comment: What happens if you add `maxlength="5"` and `echo $field->maxlength;` ?

Answer (score 1):

To specify max length in Joomla Text Field Like This

```
<fieldset name="sender_details">
    <field name="sendername"
     type="text"
     label="SENDERV_SENDER"
     description="SENDERV_SENDER_DESC"
     default=""
     maxlength="5"
     required="true" />
 </fieldset>
```

if you want your custom attribute then you can create joomla new field type or you can modify joomla form fields

```
 libraries/joomla/form/fields/text.php
 libraries/joomla/form/fields/textarea.php
 libraries/joomla/form/fields/.......
```

any problem implementing please reply

Answer (score 0):

The problem with editing core-files (libraries/joomla/form/fields/text.php,  libraries/joomla/form/fields/textarea.php,  libraries/joomla/form/fields/...) is, that with the next joomla-update these changes could be overwriten again.

Until joomla does noch correct this bug, is there any possibility to set a custom html-attribute to a jformfield before it renders with "print $field->input;" ?

edit: There already exists a bug-entry for that: http://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/3510?lang=de-DE

Answer (score 0):

You can set in edit layout like this :

```
<?php echo $this->form->getInput('fieldname','maxLength',4); ?>
```

And then your html code is :

```
<input type="text" name="jform[fieldname]" id="jform_fieldname" maxlength="4">
```